# Establishing why an object can't be pickled

Tags: python, pickle

I'm receiving an object, `t`, from an api of type `Object`. I am unable to pickle it, getting the error:

```
  File "p.py", line 55, in <module>
    pickle.dump(t, open('data.pkl', 'wb'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1362, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'Object' object: <Object object at 0xb77b11a0>
```

When I do the following:

```
for i in dir(t): print(type(i))
```

I get only string objects:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
...
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

How can I print the contents of my `Object` object in order to understand why it cant be pickled?

Its also possible that the object contains C pointers to QT objects, in which case it wouldn't make sense for me to pickle the object. But again I would like to see the internal structure of the object in order to establish this.

Comment: It seems like this is something you'd debug by investigating the `Object` type itself, not the instance.

Comment: `dir()` returns a list of string variable names, not the values of the variables themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) and check your API's  `Object` class afterwards.

With respect to the "internal structure of the object", usually instance attributes are stored in the `__dict__` attribute (and since class attributes are not pickled you only care about the instance attributes) - but note that you'll also have to recursively inspect the `__dict__`s for each attribute.

Answer (score 19):

I would use `dill`, which has tools to investigate what inside an object causes your target object to not be picklable.  See this answer for an example: [Good example of BadItem in Dill Module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26255247/2379433), and this Q&A for an example of the detection tools in real use: [pandas.algos._return_false causes PicklingError with dill.dump_session on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25508377/2379433).

```
>>> import dill
>>> x = iter([1,2,3,4])
>>> d = {'x':x}
>>> # we check for unpicklable items in d (i.e. the iterator x)
>>> dill.detect.baditems(d)
[<listiterator object at 0x10b0e48d0>]
>>> # note that nothing inside of the iterator is unpicklable!
>>> dill.detect.baditems(x)
[]
```

However, the most common starting point is to use `trace`:

```
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> dill.detect.errors(d)
D2: <dict object at 0x10b8394b0>
T4: <type 'listiterator'>
PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'listiterator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.listiterator",)
>>>
```

`dill` also has functionality to trace pointers referrers and referents to objects, so you can build a hierarchy of how objects refer to each other. See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/58

Alternately, there's also: cloudpickle.py and debugpickle.py, which are for the most part no longer developed.  I'm the `dill` author, and hope to soon merge any functionality in these codes that is missing in `dill`.

Comment: What's interesting I even have this with dill :-(

Comment: @iirekm: can you clarify what you mean by "this"?

Answer (score 3):

I tried Dill but it didn't explain my issue. Instead, I used the following code from https://gist.github.com/andresriancho/15b5e226de68a0c2efd0, which happened to show a bug in my `__getattribute__` override:

```
def debug_pickle(instance):
  """
  :return: Which attribute from this object can't be pickled?
  """
  attribute = None

  for k, v in instance.__dict__.iteritems():
      try:
          cPickle.dumps(v)
      except:
          attribute = k
          break

  return attribute
```

---

Edit: Here's a reproduction of my code, using pickle and cPickle:

```
class myDict(dict):

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        # Try to get attribute from internal dict
        item = item.replace("_", "$")

        if item in self:
            return self[item]

        # Try super, which may leads to an AttribueError
        return super(myDict, self).__getattribute__(item)

myd = myDict()

try: 
    with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as myf:
        cPickle.dump(myd, myf, protocol=-1)
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()


try:
    with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as myf:
        pickle.dump(myd, myf, protocol=-1)
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/AcceptanceTesting/ingest.py", line 35, in <module>
  cPickle.dump(myd, myf, protocol=-1)
UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <class '__main__.myDict'> objects

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/AcceptanceTesting/ingest.py", line 42, in <module>
  pickle.dump(myd, myf, protocol=-1)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
  Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
  self.save(obj)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 313, in save
  (t.__name__, obj))
PicklingError: Can't pickle 'myDict' object: {}
```

You'll see that the reason is because attribute names are being mangled by `__getattribute__`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean `dill` didn't help, but the above code did?  The above code is a weaker version of code that exists in `dill.detect`.  Specifically, `dill.detect.badobjects` and `dill.detect.badtypes`.  `dill` also has the other tools that are shown in my answer.  If there's something that `dill` is missing here, I'd like to know.

Comment: Hi @MikeMcKerns. Dill looked great, I just don't think you'll be able to code for my stupidity :) I've updated my question with a reproduction of my buggy code.

Comment: Ah… ok, you have a real corner case there.  `dill` doesn't find the problem in the case, I agree.  However, you will also note that `debug_pickle` doesn't actually return the bad attribute… it just happens to not catch the error that causes the pickling to fail. Useful, but seemingly unintentional. I'll make a note of this case as a ticket for `dill`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension of [Alastair's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35360388/1711796), in Python 3.

It:

- is recursive, to deal with complex objects where the problem might be many layers deep.

  The output is in the form `.x[i].y.z....` to allow you to see which members were called to get to the problem. With `dict` it just prints `[key/val type=...]` instead, since either keys or values can be the problem, making it harder (but not impossible) to reference a specific key or value in the `dict`.
- accounts for more types, specifically `list`, `tuple` and `dict`, which need to be handled separately, since they don't have `__dict__` attributes.
- returns all problems, rather than just the first one.

```
def get_unpicklable(instance, exception=None, string='', first_only=True):
    """
    Recursively go through all attributes of instance and return a list of whatever
    can't be pickled.

    Set first_only to only print the first problematic element in a list, tuple or
    dict (otherwise there could be lots of duplication).
    """
    problems = []
    if isinstance(instance, tuple) or isinstance(instance, list):
        for k, v in enumerate(instance):
            try:
                pickle.dumps(v)
            except BaseException as e:
                problems.extend(get_unpicklable(v, e, string + f'[{k}]'))
                if first_only:
                    break
    elif isinstance(instance, dict):
        for k in instance:
            try:
                pickle.dumps(k)
            except BaseException as e:
                problems.extend(get_unpicklable(
                    k, e, string + f'[key type={type(k).__name__}]'
                ))
                if first_only:
                    break
        for v in instance.values():
            try:
                pickle.dumps(v)
            except BaseException as e:
                problems.extend(get_unpicklable(
                    v, e, string + f'[val type={type(v).__name__}]'
                ))
                if first_only:
                    break
    else:
        for k, v in instance.__dict__.items():
            try:
                pickle.dumps(v)
            except BaseException as e:
                problems.extend(get_unpicklable(v, e, string + '.' + k))

    # if we get here, it means pickling instance caused an exception (string is not
    # empty), yet no member was a problem (problems is empty), thus instance itself
    # is the problem.
    if string != '' and not problems:
        problems.append(
            string + f" (Type '{type(instance).__name__}' caused: {exception})"
        )

    return problems
```

Comment: Some types end up in the `else` clause that don't have a `__dict__`, eg, methods. I just ignored `AttributeError` if raised by `__dict__`.