# Can't pickle local object 'Styler' in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f29e1969430>.

I need to return this data through a return function, but I get this error:

```
'ERROR - Can't pickle local object 'Styler.applymap.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

I don't know what's the meaning of that sentence.

Tha's the code I trying to pass in a return function:

```py
def dag_transform_data(**kwargs):
    charges = kwargs["ti"].xcom_pull("get_charges_report")
    active_payments = kwargs["ti"].xcom_pull("get_active_payments_report")
    return_payments = kwargs["ti"].xcom_pull("get_return_payments_report")
    return transform_data(charges, active_payments, return_payments)
```

This function returns <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f29e1969430>.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499341/establishing-why-an-object-cant-be-pickled) for info. Essentially classes cannot be pickled - only more simple objects. Pickling is a object  applied to an object to pass it between processes as a byte string.

Comment: If you're asking for a solution, please include a minimally reproducible example - including the (minimal) code that creates this issue.

Comment: @Roy2012, yes, sorry, I added it.

Comment: It's still not a minimal reproducible example. I don't know how to call this function, and transform_data isn't defined. It the issue is with Styler, maybe all you need for an MRE is to create such a styler and try to pickle it?